# Возможно ли двустороннее взаимное изменение MySQL таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Предположим есть две таблицы "teacher" и "schoolClass".

```
"teacher": ID, Name; classID.
"schoolClass": ID, Name, TeacherID
```

**"teacher.classID"** - показывает на ID из "schoolClass", **"schoolClass.TeacherID"** - указывает на ID учителя в первой таблице.
Возможно ли на уровне базы сделать так, чтобы при сохранении(добавлении) учителя с заполненным **"classID"**, изменения были отражены и в таблице **"schoolClass":TeacherID** и наоборот: при сохранении класса  - изменения происходили и в "teacher". В какую сторону гуглить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого делать нельзя и, главное, не нужно. Представим, что например, мы имеем отношение "многие к одному", тогда у нас возникает проблема, при изменении той стороны что содержит "многих", проблема эта - каким значением из множества ключей на стороне "многих" мы должны обновить поле на стороне "одного". Отношения "многие ко многим" решаются созданием дополнительной таблицы. А отношение "один к одному" удалением `FOREIGN KEY`, из одной таблицы. И добавлением к полю другой таблицы ограничения, кроме `FOREIGN KEY`, `UNIQUE`, и возможно `CASCADE`.

Вам надо почитать про нормализацию данных.